# Permitir somente letras maiúsculas no EditText

Tags: android, edittext

Sei que posso fazer com que a tela do EditText fique sempre rotacionada, agora quero saber se tem como só permitir letras maiúsculas no momento em que o usuário for digitar algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O android possui um `InputFilter` para isso, como você pode ver na [documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps.html). Com isso basta setar o filtro através do método `setFilters()` do seu `EditText`.

Ex:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você colocar `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` no XML ele vai priorizar a letra maiúscula, porém o usuário poderá mudar dependendo do dispositivo, então sugiro que você contole na hora de pegar os dados do input da seguinte forma:

```
String algumaString = seuEdittext.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

O EditText tem um propriedade chamada setInputType que recebe um valor int da classe InputType onde voce consegue mudar programaticamente a entrada do usuario enquanto ele esta digitando, porem creio nao ser possivel limitar apenas caracteres pois dependendo do teclado do dispositivo e possivel o usuario clicar no botao de simbolos e selecionar um numero por exemplo.

Answer (score -2):

No EditText há uma propriedade chamado CharCase, para Maiuscula coloque em UpperCase e para Minúsculas LowerCase. espero ter ajudado.